# How to handle file_get_contents failed error message?

Tags: file-get-contents

I am running a request to the youtube data api.

The user inputs there account name, saves the settings and then checks the page for what videos are on there account -

If they enter their account name wrong, or the account name doesn't exist I want it to display an error message clarifying that they have entered an incorrect account name.

If it is successful it should just print the videos in a list.

I have it printing videos/pulling videos from youtube if the account name is correct. If it is wrong, I get a `File_Get_Contents` failed -

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ddd/uploads?
v=2&alt=json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-content\plugins\plugin\includes\get_vid_list.php on 
line 379
```

I would like, instead of printing the error I want it to print an error message to the user:

How do I check if `file_get_contents()` was successful or not?

Comment: I have tried 
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
    if($data === false) { print error message }

Comment: f_g_c is a very simplistic tool. If you want better control over failures, you should use something better suited to handle everything an HTTP request can throw at you, like CURL.

Comment: would it be difficult to switch from a f_g_c call to a CURL request?
aka would this involve hacking up a good deal of my code?

Comment: Search SO for `curl_exec` and you'll see lots of examples of how to use `curl`.

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP's `@` modifier to suppress automatic error reporting:

```
$contents = @file_get_contents($url);
if (!$contents) {
    // Report error
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it suppresses my error and displays nothing. I have a custom error message that I would like to display

Comment: Did you replace `// Report error` with code to echo your custom error message?